# Next.js 13 NextAuth in docker image is not signing in

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next-auth, next.js13

The issue start to occur when working on docker.

The problem is that when docker is up, I'm going into port specified and try to SignIn giving credentials, nothing is happening apart of receiving 2 calls

[image: First answer from server]

[image: Second answer from server]

[image: Redirection into protected routes]

I stuck, can't see anywhere what might cause an issue atm. Frontend suppose to communicate with backend and also receive another token from it, so the rest of the calls are made with Auth option. Backend is stored locally atm with Django.

I already tried specify NEXTAUTH_URL into localhost:3000 but also 8000 that correspond backend localhost - none of this help.

Anyone has any idea how to fix such issue?